# Concatenate XML in BPEL 2.0

Tags: xslt-1.0, bpel

Need your help for a requirement in BPEL 2.0. I have a collection in the below format

```
<FilesCollection>
      <Files>
        <transactionid>
        <status>
        <filename>
      <Files>
<FilesCollection>
```

I would be getting several such collections while traversing through a ForEach loop.

Once I have exited the loop , I need to concatenate all the collections so that finally I get something as below

```
<FilesCollection>
          <Files>
            <transactionid>
            <status>
            <filename>
          <Files>
          <Files>
            <transactionid>
            <status>
            <filename>
          <Files>
          <Files>
            <transactionid>
            <status>
            <filename>
          <Files>
 <FilesCollection>
```

Please note that the number of FilesCollection element and the number of Files element appearing within it would be dynamic.

Please help me with this.

Thanks
Arijit

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you have multiple `FilesCollection` in XML document and you want to wrap inside one then you need to do something like this:

**Note:** Suppose your root element is root in source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <FilesCollection>
                <xsl:copy-of select="FilesCollection/node()"/>
            </FilesCollection>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```